# how to create an android application to control PC command line?

Tags: android

The question says it all... What i am trying to do is find an application which can connect to a pc and take control of the command line?

Anyone know of any tutorials that teach me and show me how to do this?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remote droid](http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/) seems like what you want. Its GPL so please respect the license.

Comment: Click Source > Browse > trunk